# are beta sites neutrinos to the supercollider

Tags: bug, status-norepro, recent-activity

A question of mine on music got an answer, and I'm fairly sure that it never appeared as a response in the superconducting supercollider reminder. Is that on purpose, by accident, or evidence that I'm not paying attention?

Comment: Is it [this question's answer](http://music.stackexchange.com/questions/94/sibelius-op-75-number-5-is-the-composer-a-bit-sloppy-is-my-edition-a-bit-slopp)? That was during the private beta, which might explain it.

Comment: That's the one.

Comment: @waiwai wai remove my silliness about by purpose or on accident?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't confirm -- that answer appears in your inbox. Try looking (as I did) at the **inbox tab on your network profile** (this is linked from your user page) on that date.

https://stackexchange.com/users/7bc119e9-133f-4adc-b2ec-f54a180919cc?tab=inbox